# iPhone 6 Plus Unlocking

Tags: iphone, unlock

I have been trying to unlock my iPhone 6 Plus which is locked to TMobile. The instructions which they sent me read as follows:

> Thank you for taking the time to contact T-Mobile. 24 hours after
>   receiving this email, follow the below instructions for unlocking your
>   T-Mobile iPhone. If you have a non-T-Mobile SIM card, follow these
>   steps:
>
> If you have a non-T-Mobile SIM card:
>   1. Insert non T-Mobile SIM Card
>   2. Complete the setup process.
>
> If you will be using your T-Mobile SIM card follow the steps below:
>
> 1. Back up your iPhone using iTunes.
> 2. When you have a backup, erase your iPhone.
> 3. When you see the Welcome screen, connect your device to iTunes.
>
> If successfully unlocked, the message Congratulations, your iPhone has
>   been unlocked will display. Additional information for unlocking Apple
>   iPhone devices can be located at
>   https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201328

I performed all the operations, which have been a pain the neck in their own right. Now I have a fully erased and restored phone on my hands. What I am wondering about is how to actually check to make sure it worked. That is, I am planning to use it abroad and would like to avoid hiccups like arriving to a new place and discovering that for some reason this did not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Before your trip, find a friend whose cell phone connects with a carrier other than T-Mobile (and not an MVNO that connects via T-Mobile), and whose phone has a SIM card of the same size.

Put the friend's SIM card in your phone. If the phone connects, your phone has been unlocked.